# Gatsby Functional Component Event Handling Passing 'this'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, gatsby

Using a Gatsby/React functional component, how do I pass `this` to an event handler? I need to manage the css classes of `<figure>` via "classList".

```
import React from 'react'

const Hamburger = props => {
  const clickHandler = () => {
    this.classList.toggle('open')
  }
  return (
    <figure className="hamburger open" onClick={clickHandler.bind(this)}>
      <i>menu</i>
    </figure>
  )
}

export default Hamburger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- Arrow functions don't have their own `this`, so the browser cannot actually set `this` of the click handler to the element.
- But the bigger issue is that you shouldn't be changing the DOM directly when you use React.

The way to do this with React is to keep track of whether the component is open or not via state (in this case the [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)), and set the class list accordingly:

```js
import React from 'react'

const {useState} = React;

export default const Hamburger = props => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <figure className={'hamburger' + (open ? ' open' : '')} onClick={clickHandler}>
      <i>menu</i>
    </figure>
  )
}

export default Hamburger
```

Comment: It looks to be working; I'm just attempting to wrap my brain around the code now. Could you briefly explain the line containing 'useState'?

Comment: Got it... React Hooks.

Comment: Yep, sorry for not explaining that more, I added a link to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the first `props => {` to `function(props){`, function will create a closure for `this`, if there's no function, `this` will find the outer closure

```
import React from 'react'

const Hamburger = function(props){
  const clickHandler = () => {
    \\ classList.toggle('open')
  }
  return (
    <figure className="hamburger open" onClick={clickHandler}>
      <i>menu</i>
    </figure>
  )
}

export default Hamburger
```

Comment: No change. I've binded 'this' to the clickHandler now, which may be a step in the right direction.

Comment: @RyanPrentiss: Functional components don't use `this` and you cannot bind `this` of an arrow function.

Comment: This won't help the OP either. `this` won't refer to the DOM element and they shouldn't be mutating the DOM in the first place.